# Enthought Canopy ipython configuration: bad interpreter No such file or directory

Tags: ipython, enthought

I'm trying to launch Enthought Canopy's ipython from a Terminal in Mac OS 10.8.3 using the following command:

```
/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.0.0.1160.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/bin/ipython
```

but I'm receiving the following error:

```
/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.0.0.1160.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/bin/ipython: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.1/Resources/Python.app/Content: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

This (7.1) framework was previously installed but was removed long ago, so I can't quite figure out where Canopy's IPython is getting this link from. I've checked my ./ipython/profile_default directory as well but this didn't help.

Any idea how I might be able to launch ipython from a Terminal?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Canopy uses virtual environments to setup a user environment which is isolated from the environment in which the app itself is running.  This prevents any changes made to the environment, by the user, from crashing the application itself.

To run an IPython terminal, with access to any packages that you may have installed via the package manager, you should run IPython from the User environment -- `~/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/ipython`

Comment: Thank you!  After playing around some more I noticed that, when first launching Canopy, if you select "use this as the default Python installation", then links are created so you can just enter "ipython" in a Terminal.

I think I understand virtual environments, but I don't understand why attempting a Terminal launch of ipython (the one buried in Canopy.app) tries to access an old, non-existent Python installation. Where is that link stored?  Could you recommend any reading about virtual environments that might help me understand more clearly?

Comment: The error you are seeing is because, Canopy is built into an application and shipped to you, and the ipython script has the interpreter pointing to the location on the build machine. (Look at the first line of `/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.0.0.1160.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/bin/ipython`).  To run this ipython script, you can run the following `/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.0.0.1160.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/bin/python /Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.0.0.1160.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/bin/ipython`